# Google Analytics Goals Funnel With Same Destination

Tags: google-analytics

I have 3 pages which lead to the same destination (thank you page) as follow.

```
Home > a / b / c
a > inquiry > thank you
b > inquiry > thank you
c > inquiry > thank you
```

What way is the proper way to set the goal or funnel, so that i can know which page (a/b/c) visitor goes through before filling in inquiry?

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper way. Goals with the same destination are the same goal, and they will be tracked regardless of funnel settings (funnel is for visualization only). Also funnel cannot be segmented or filtered.

You could set a cookie with different values for a,b,c and based on those cookies pass in virtual urls to get different goal urls. That would get you different goal urls, but in your content report you'd have three different rows for your thank-you page.

Based on the same idea you could have an event based goal with a value based on the cookie with the previously visited page. Event based goals do not have funnels, but you could use segments of the "sequence" type to analyze users with the specific flow.